# If User signin fails twice, i have to get recaptcha in the form using devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to developing in Ruby on Rails. In my application, I am using Recaptcha in devise signin form. My requirement is: Recaptcha has to generate if user fails to signin twice in  a row.

*This is my session controller:*

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [
      :new,:create ]

  prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only => :create

  prepend_before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

  def create
    if verify_recaptcha

      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?

      sign_in(resource_name, resource)

      respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

    else

      flash[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code and click submit."

      flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)

      render :new

    end    end
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)      user_dashboard_path   end

  end
end
```

*users/sessions/new.html.erb:*

```
        <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
            <div>Sign in</div>
            <div>

              <div><p><%= f.label :email, "Email" %></p><%= f.email_field :email %></div>
              <div><p><%= f.label :password, "Password" %></p><%= f.password_field :password %></div>

                  <div><div id="customize_recaptcha"><%= raw recaptcha_tags %></div></div>
              <%end%>

            </div>
            <div class="footer">

              <div class="button"><%= f.submit 'Sign in'%></a></div>
            </div>
        <% end%>
```

Comment: simply put a counter with login page request and handle accordingly.

Comment: Can you please give me one example or any link regarding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235619/enable-captcha-after-several-login-failure-how-to-implement-this?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368055/devise-add-captcha-to-login-page-after-x-failed-logins, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042512/devise-capcha-on-x-wrong-passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an idea from this too:

I think you should be able to use the [`lockable`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Lockable) module with
lock_strategy set to `:failed_attempts` and `unlock_strategy` set to `:none`
meaning you'll handle it manually, but instead of trying to lock the
account, just use the `failed_attempts` field to determine when to show
the captcha. The best part is that the `failed_attempts` for a user is reset to zero once the
user successfully logs in.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gopal. I got it by using cookies[:login_attempts] matching with email.